# How to uninstall mathematica 9 from Ubuntu?

Tags: uninstall

I'd like to know how can I uninstall Mathematica from Ubuntu.

apt-get remove does not work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The link http://support.wolfram.com/kb/4730 provides the following information:

**Linux**

To uninstall Mathematica, please remove the following directories. Please back up any documents that you want to keep from these directories:

```
/usr/share/Mathematica/
~/.Mathematica/Licensing/mathpass
/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/
```

Comment: Also worth mentioning that one cannot use `apt-get remove` to uninstall an application for which `apt-get install` was not used to install it.

Answer (score 6):

Simply remove the installation directory (evaluate `$InstallationDirectory` within Mathematica to find it). Mathematica 9 is delivered as a self-extracting shell script, rather than a package.

If you asked the installer to create symlinks for the `math`, `MathKernel`, and `Mathematica` commands, e.g. in `/usr/local/bin/` you could remove those as well.

You can backup the user setting in `$BaseDirectory` (`/usr/share/Mathematica`) and `$UserBaseDirectory` (`~/.Mathematica`) as desired.

Comment: For Mathematica 10, the complete list of symlinks in `/usr/local/bin` should be `MathKernel`, `Mathematica`, `WolframKernel`, `math`,
`mathematica`, `mcc`, `wolfram`

Answer (score 6):

To remove completely, including icons and links to use these codes:

```
rm -R ~/.Mathematica
sudo rm -R /usr/share/Mathematica
sudo rm -R /usr/local/Wolfram
sudo rm /usr/share/man/man1/mathematica.1
sudo rm /usr/share/mime/application/mathematica.xml
sudo rm /usr/share/mime/application/mathematicaplayer.xml
sudo rm /usr/share/mime/packages/wolfram-mathematica.xml
sudo rm /usr/share/mime/packages/wolfram-mathematicaplayer.xml
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/mathematica
sudo rm /usr/local/share/applications/wolfram-mathematica9.desktop
sudo rm /usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps/wolfram-mathematica.png
sudo rm /usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/apps/wolfram-mathematicaplayer.png
sudo rm /usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/mimetypes/application-mathematica.png
sudo rm /usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/mimetypes/application-mathematicaplayer.png
sudo rm /usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/mimetypes/gnome-mime-application-mathematica.png
sudo rm /usr/share/icons/hicolor/128x128/mimetypes/gnome-mime-application-mathematicaplayer.png
sudo rm /usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/wolfram-mathematica.png
sudo rm /usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/apps/wolfram-mathematicaplayer.png
sudo rm /usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/mimetypes/application-mathematica.png
sudo rm /usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/mimetypes/application-mathematicaplayer.png
sudo rm /usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/mimetypes/gnome-mime-application-mathematica.png
sudo rm /usr/share/icons/hicolor/32x32/mimetypes/gnome-mime-application-mathematicaplayer.png
sudo rm /usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/apps/wolfram-mathematica.png
sudo rm /usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/apps/wolfram-mathematicaplayer.png
sudo rm /usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/mimetypes/application-mathematica.png
sudo rm /usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/mimetypes/application-mathematicaplayer.png
sudo rm /usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/mimetypes/gnome-mime-application-mathematica.png
sudo rm /usr/share/icons/hicolor/64x64/mimetypes/gnome-mime-application-mathematicaplayer.png
```